# OpenLDAP TLS CA configuration

Tags: openldap, tls

I'm currently in the process of setting up two sychronized OpenLDAP servers, access through starttls/ldaps. On the client/slave, I had problems with the TLS connection. I'm using the directory-based configuration, and  `olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/root-ca.pem` is set, `root-ca.pem` is readable for user `ldap`.

However, starttls and ldaps connection fail:

```
ldapwhoami -x -H ldap://192.168.56.201/ -ZZ
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
    additional info: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

If I add a `ldaprc` file to the current directory with the following entry

`TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/certs/root-ca.pem`

everthing works as expected.

So it seems the `olcTLSCACertificateFile` setting is being ignored, or could there be any other errors / misconfigurations I'm missing? OS is Suse Enterprise 11sp4, OpenLDAP version is 2.4.26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ldapwhoami is an LDAP client tool.  It does not use the olcTLSCACertificateFile parameter.  That is a server-side paramater for slapd.

You need to specify somewhere, that the client tools understand, that you trust the CA.  This can be done (as you have done) in the ldaprc file, in the global /etc/ldap/ldap.conf file, by being overly permissive in your CA checking (TLS_REQCERT allow  ...not recommended), or maybe the best option is to add your CA to be trusted by the system itself by doing this (on Debian at least, ymmv):

1. Copy your (PEM-encoded) CA certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` on the client machine.
2. Run `# update-ca-certificates`
3. This will update the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` collection of CAs, which should already be specified in your /etc/ldap/ldap.conf file and your CA will be trusted by ldapwhoami and other tools.

Comment: FIrst part of your answer solved my issue: I tried to check the slapd-configuration with client tools that do not use the olcTLS* parameters. The slapd-configuration was correct: After adding starttls=yes to the syncrepl entry, connections between consumer and producer are encrypted, no more certificate verification errors.